# Is it possible to have a object and a list separately in yaml? YAML Syntax Error

Tags: syntax, yaml

I'm wondering why I get the `Implicit keys need to be on a single line` and `Implicit map keys need to be followed by map value` errors from the following example. Is it possible to have an object and a list separately in yaml?

```
# This is a comment

# These are key-value pairs
app: user-auth
port: 22
version: 1.1

# This is an object
microservices: 
  app: user-auth
  port: 22
  version: 1.1

# This is a list
- one
- two 
- three
```

I tried adding the list in different positions in the file to no avail. It doesn't give the error if the rest is commented out, so I'm wondering why it gives the errors.

Comment: Your example is not valid yaml. You can learn yaml by following online ressources. A good one IMO is [Learn Yaml in Y minutes](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/). You can validate your yaml content using [yamllint](https://yamllint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) prior to posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have both an object and a list separately in YAML. However, it is important to use the correct syntax. In this case you are missing a colon (:).

```
object:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
list:
  - item1
  - item2
  - item3
```